# How to Calculate sum of all the digits in text file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am having  text file t.txt,I want to calculate sum of all the digits in text file 
Example

```
    --- t.txt ---
The rahul  jumped in 2 the well. The water was cold at 1 degree Centigrade. There were 3 grip holes on the walls.  The well was 17 feet deep.
--- EOF --
```

sum 2+1+3+1+7
My ruby code to calculate sum is

```
ruby -e "File.read('t.txt').split.inject(0){|mem, obj| mem += obj.to_f}"
```

But i am not getting any answer??

Comment: Note that `inject` uses the block's return value, the assignment is superfluous. In other words: you should use `mem + ...` instead of `mem += ...` within the block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement is computing correctly. Just add puts before File read as:

```
ruby -e "puts File.read('t.txt').split.inject(0){|mem, obj| mem += obj.to_f}"
# => 23.0
```

For summing single digit only:

```
ruby -e "puts File.read('t.txt').scan(/\d/).inject(0){|mem, obj| mem += obj.to_f}"
# => 14.0
```

Thanks

Comment: Ohk, you want only single digit to be summed up. Updating the answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
str = "The rahul  jumped in 2 the well. The water was cold at 1 degree Centigrade. There were 3 grip holes on the walls.  The well was 17 feet deep."
```

To get sum of all integers:

```
str.scan(/\d+/).sum(&:to_i)
# => 23
```

Or to get sum of all digits as in your example:

```
str.scan(/\d+?/).sum(&:to_i)
# => 14
```

PS: I used `sum` seeing `Rails` tag. If you are only using Ruby you can use `inject` instead.
Example with [`inject`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject)

```
str.scan(/\d/).inject(0) { |sum, a| sum + a.to_i }
# => 14
str.scan(/\d+/).inject(0) { |sum, a| sum + a.to_i }
# => 23
```

Comment: inject is not working,it is giving error   " to_i': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)"

Comment: You can use `/\d/` instead of `/\d+?/`